# Generics and varargs java

Tags: java, generics, interface, variadic-functions

Below is my set up

```
public interface Test<T extends MyInterface> 
{
    someMethod(T... a)
}

public class TestImpl implements Test<MyInterfaceImpl> 
{
    someMethod(MyInterfaceImpl... a)
}

public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {}

public someClass { @Autowired TestFactory testfactory 

......

// getting an error --  Type mismatch Can't assign non-array value to an array 
testfactory.getTest(Type type).someMethod(new MyInterfaceImpl()) 

}

public class TestFactoryImpl implements TestFactory { Test getTest(Type type) { return registry.get(type)}}
```

which in turn is results in java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lcom.test.MyInterface; cannot be cast to [Lcom.test.Impl.MyInterfaceImpl;

but the below works

```
testfactory.getTest(Type type).someMethod(new MyInterfaceImpl[]{new MyInterfaceImpl()})
```

Not sure what is happening. Help please

Comment: Why is `new MyInterfaceImpl` not `new MyInterfaceImpl()`?

Comment: sorry. that's a typo error in the question. Changed in the question

Comment: Is your `Test` object actually a raw type? Raw types, generics, and varargs can cause confusing errors. There's actually a famous Java puzzler by Josh Bloch with a similar setup.

Comment: @TomG no my test object is an instance of TestImpl bean

Comment: Can you post some actual minimal non-pseudo-code which will let us reproduce problem you are facing? I'm having problem with reproducing it http://ideone.com/UiVqEP.

Comment: @user883275 My question still stands. Your `Test` interface requires a generic parameter that you're not providing in `someClass`, which should be causing a compiler warning about raw types. Add at the very least a wildcard type to `Test` like so -- `Test<? extends MyInterface>`.

Comment: Are you sure `test.someMethod(new MyInterfaceImpl(),new MyInterfaceImpl())` works?

Comment: @Mohammad sorry I get the same error for test.someMethod(new MyInterfaceImpl(),new MyInterfaceImpl())

Answer (score 5):

Ok .. the problem is within the design of your already existing code (which you can't change). Having `public interface Test<T extends MyInterface>` and then `public class TestImpl implements Test<MyInterfaceImpl>` is wrong.

`TestImpl` is implementing `Test` with `MyInterfaceImpl` whereas the original `Test` interface only expects an object that `extends`  `MyInterface` and not implement it.

There will be a type confusion at runtime when executing the code. Not only does the following line throw a `ClassCastException`

```
test.someMethod(new MyInterfaceImpl());
```

but also `test.someMethod();` by itself throws an exception. So let's say if you factory called this method passing no argument, you would still get an exception as the original designed is flawed. In a normal situation `test.someMethod();` should not throw an exception to begin with. You will need to talk to the appropriate party to put a fix to this serious issue.

### Below is a sample solution:

The method `someMethod(MyInterface...)` belongs to the raw type `Test`. References to generic type `Test<T>` should be parameterized.

This means you should `Test<MyInterfaceImpl> test` to avoid getting this error with only the `new` operator.

```
Test<MyInterfaceImpl> test
...
test.someMethod(new MyInterfaceImpl());
```

The above code will work with no problem.

Comment: the suggested works but I actually get test object via a factory ..like the below code but not exactly the same. 


Test getImpl(Type type) {return new TestImpl()}

Comment: also this solution does explain the fact that y the below code works test.someMethod(new MyInterfaceImpl[]{new MyInterfaceImpl()})

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is in your `TestImpl` class do the following

```
public class TestImpl implements Test<MyInterface>{...}
```

instead of

```
public class TestImpl implements Test<MyInterfaceImpl>{...}
```

That way you don't need to explicitly parameterize your object instance (i.e. you could just do

```
Test test
...
test.someMethod(new MyInterfaceImpl());
```

)

Comment: You should place this additional information into your first answer by editing it.

Comment: @Mohammad we dont want to make this change as in future we want to use MyInterfaceImpl in public class TestImpl implements Test<MyInterfaceImpl>{...}